# How to add enviroment specific test in travis CI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, travis-ci

I am developing some project and i am using travis CI for unit testing and I want that using environment variable I can use phantomjs in case of travis (using phantomjs as travis won't support gui) and I can use firefox/chrome in case of desktop usage.
How can i do this in python? I tried to google but i am confused what should i search.

Comment: So you want two builds, one with phantomjs enabled and one with it disabled?